# Making my layout better looking

Tags: android, android-layout

I am looking for design, look and feel suggestions based on what I currently have - which is ugly:
http://screencast.com/t/mjHawFeFnbRb

It is basically a listview as such:
*

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/news_name_placeholder"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/news_date_placeholder"      
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>
```

It is clearly hard on the eyes, so I'm hoping I can get some great ideas on how to make it more enjoyable for the user, and really to make it look sexy.

Each line can be different depending on the data, so either I need them as they are, or another way to indicate the incoming data in 3 different states (currently red, yellow, green).

what would I call this type of element http://41.media.tumblr.com/91b9c05d7af1016675da74a7a232f39d/tumblr_mloupiH0gn1snfpwco1_400.png in order to search how to do it ?

Hopefully that gets the design ideas flowing :)
thx

Comment: dont use color that distract eyes... use simple colors and simple views for more effective layouts

Comment: Try changing the colors as @Prag'sシ Said, take a look here: http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-ui-color-application

Comment: im thinking something like this: http://41.media.tumblr.com/91b9c05d7af1016675da74a7a232f39d/tumblr_mloupiH0gn1snfpwco1_400.png  if i could make the grey part at the top contain the time, and the blue part have the details , i think that would look good ? Can anyone suggest how that is done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to make something from scratch which you can build on, the desired look which you want to achieve (in screenshot) is professional and will be hard to get source of / make.

Here is what I've got, intead of changing the text color and making peoples eyes bleed you could have a color on the side representing the status (I'm guessing that's what it is).

**Screenshot 1:**
Top bar is fixed to the top, events are displayed below with their corresponding priority / status.

[image: Screenshot 1]

**Screenshot 2:**
Top bar stays at the top and allows you to scroll down to see all the events.

[image: Screenshot 2]

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#F7C26D"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.testdesignapp.MainActivity" 
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="#eda737"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Top bar " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Non scrolling " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="If needed" />

</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/green" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView1"
                android:text="Spanish unemployment change 19:00"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
                android:text="This could be extra detail about the event, such as the date 02-12-2014 19:00 GMT."
                android:textColor="#595959"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/yellow" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView2"
                android:text="Spanish unemployment change 19:00"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
                android:text="This could be extra detail about the event, such as the date 02-12-2014 19:00 GMT."
                android:textColor="#595959"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/red" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView3"
                android:text="Spanish unemployment change 19:00"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
                android:text="This could be extra detail about the event, such as the date 02-12-2014 19:00 GMT."
                android:textColor="#595959"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/green" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView4"
                android:text="Spanish unemployment change 19:00"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView10"
                android:text="This could be extra detail about the event, such as the date 02-12-2014 19:00 GMT."
                android:textColor="#595959"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/yellow" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView12"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView5"
                android:text="Spanish unemployment change 19:00"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView13"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView12"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView12"
                android:text="This could be extra detail about the event, such as the date 02-12-2014 19:00 GMT."
                android:textColor="#595959"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/red" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView14"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView7"
                android:text="Spanish unemployment change 19:00"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView15"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView14"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView14"
                android:text="This could be extra detail about the event, such as the date 02-12-2014 19:00 GMT."
                android:textColor="#595959"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/green" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView16"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView8"
                android:text="Spanish unemployment change 19:00"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView17"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView16"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView16"
                android:text="This could be extra detail about the event, such as the date 02-12-2014 19:00 GMT."
                android:textColor="#595959"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/yellow" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView18"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView9"
                android:text="Spanish unemployment change 19:00"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView19"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView18"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView18"
                android:text="This could be extra detail about the event, such as the date 02-12-2014 19:00 GMT."
                android:textColor="#595959"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/red" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView20"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView10"
                android:text="Spanish unemployment change 19:00"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView21"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView20"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView20"
                android:text="This could be extra detail about the event, such as the date 02-12-2014 19:00 GMT."
                android:textColor="#595959"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

The 3 images I used (green, yellow, red) you can generate [**HERE**](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-generic.html#source.type=clipart&source.space.trim=0&source.space.pad=-0.1&source.clipart=res%2Fclipart%2Ficons%2Fav_stop.svg&size=64&padding=4&color=fffa47%2C100&name=yellow)

Hope I helped, good luck! ;)

Markus

Comment: No problem, hope you will make use of it or some parts at least :)

Comment: i have stripped the dupes out of your layout as I'm inflating them dynamically with an adapter, for some reason when I did that (including the header layout), i'm getting the following padding http://screencast.com/t/QURvBfmSyKla

Comment: The individual layouts are `wrap_content`, to make the color orange go all the way to the end set the `android:layout_width` to `match_parent` for each of the `RelativeLayouts` :) EDIT: If you already have `match_parent` set then try doing the same for each of the `TextViews`, if that doesn't work try setting background color for each of the `RelativeLayouts` indivually.

Comment: well I think i'm getting there, thx to you :) http://screencast.com/t/AyDhm0a70D  Just need to align the icons a bit better and maybe add a few more sexy touches .. thx again :)

Comment: I'm glad it's working out ;) Here are two quick ideas I put togather in photoshop, will save you a bit of space http://i.imgur.com/Pf8MmTt.png If my original reply + comments answer your question then feel free to mark it as complete. Best of luck !

Answer (score 0):

Take two more LinearLayout instead directly put left and right TextView as direct child and set weight which can show like left as label and right as value pair data :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.30">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/news_name_placeholder"
            style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.70"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/news_date_placeholder"
            style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thx, thats a good start, i'm also looking for suggestions on the text itself, fonts, colors, backgrounds, special effects ? anything that could help it look really good , thx :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your item LinearLayout orientaltion to vertical, since a single line is not enough to put your information. And change the text size of your two TextViews, I think textView1 must be larger than textView2.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/news_name_placeholder"
        style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/news_date_placeholder"      
        android:gravity="left"
        style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```